# jQuery click event inside prototype extend

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```
;(function($, document, window) {
    'use strict';
    var defaults = {
        el: '.na', 
    };
    $.fn.baboy = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
     this.each(function(){       
        var dis = $(this);
      $('body').on('click', dis, function(e) {
        var text = dis.text();
        $( settings.el ).append('Click ' +  text + '</br>' );
      });
    });  
    };
})(jQuery, document, window);
```

Then I wanted to use it on two elements

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Button 1</a>
<p class="duh"></p>

<a href="#" class="btn2">Button 2</a>
<p class="duh2"></p>
```

using the function in two elements

```
$('.btn').baboy({
    el: '.duh',
});

$('.btn2').baboy({
    el: '.duh2',
});
```

However, everytime I click any of the a tag, it seems like the other one also runs.

Here the fiddle to see the issue https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/100340/

Comment: `$('body').on('click', dis, function(e) {` looks weird.  The second argument to `on()` there should be a selector, but you are giving it a jQuery object.  I'm not even sure why you are doing a delegate there.  You already have the object you are trying to process events on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using a jQuery object in the selector argument of the delegated `on()` call. Quite why this then affects all elements not the bound one I'm not sure without digging in to the jQuery source. However I can say that your usage is incorrect; that argument should be a string.

That said, you don't need a delegated event handler at all. You don't need the `each()` either. You can create the `click()` event handler on the element(s) the plugin was instantiated on, like this:

```js
;(function($, document, window) {
  'use strict';
  var defaults = {
    el: '.na',
  };
  
  $.fn.baboy = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.on('click', function() {
      $(settings.el).append('Click ' + $(this).text() + '</br>');
    });
  };
})(jQuery, document, window);

$('.btn').baboy({
  el: '.duh',
});

$('.btn2').baboy({
  el: '.duh2',
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #a3de14;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.duh,
.duh2 {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="btn">Button 1</a>
<p class="duh"></p>

<a href="#" class="btn2">Button 2</a>
<p class="duh2"></p>
```

You should also note that this plugin is massive overkill, as the logic for all button instances can be distilled in to a single event handler with 3 lines of code. However I'm going to assume this is just a learning exercise.